# LDAP query to return user

Tags: active-directory, ldap

From a distinguished name, I am trying to retrieve an Active Directory user record using LDAP.  Here is the query I am sending...

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(CN=George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL))
```

However, this returns no results.

If I use...

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(CN=George Hutchins))
```

I get the record returned.  I would just use the latter query, but if there are two George Hutchins, then I will get 2 records instead of the one I am looking for.

Is there a way to query to get the exact user with the distinguished name (CN=George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL)?  Btw, I know this string is correct as I pulled it from a Group record (member property) in Active Directory.

Comment: If there are two George Hutchens and they are both contractors this won't save you anyway. You have to make sure that the entries are unique regardless of position in the DIT. That means using something unique about the user for the search, such as a UID, his email, a 'screen name', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fully Distinguished name will ALWAYS be unique within LDAP.

A simple query like similar to:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

and setting a Search Base to:

```
(CN=George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL)
```

with a Search Scope of: `BASE (0)`
Within your [Search Request](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SearchRequest) should work.

-jim

Answer (score 1):

You could specifically query using the `distinguishedName` attribute:

`(distinguishedName=CN=George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL)`

The reason your original query didn't work is because of this part: `(CN=George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL)`. What that's asking for AD to return is LDAP objects that have a `CN` attribute with a value of `George Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=MYCO,DC=LOCAL`. However, the `CN` for him would only be `George Hutchins`.